# How to prevent top layer of a stack to affect on bottom layers tapping

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How in a stack, prevent the upper layer of affect the tapping on the lower layers.
In other words, in my case, I need a color layer that is placed on top of the first element, but does not affect the tapping on the layer below.
I used a container for colored box

[image: Middle colored box does not let tapping bottom layer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it in [IgnorePointer();](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

```
Stack(
  children: [
     firstElement,
     IgnorePointer(child: colorLayer),
  ],
)
```